# Visual basic 6.0 simple application set in Task Scheduler

Tags: vb6, scheduled-tasks

I have a requirement to create an application to upload data into database from csv file which run in a specific date. The only programming language that the company allowed is to use Visual Basic 6.0 or VBA. I already create an application using a standard exe file in Visual basic 6.0. Is there any way around how to create this this with using form control in Visual Basic 6.0? I know .Net is much better to creat this, but I am not allowed to use .Net technologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can.  Just make a standard exe as you already did.  Then add a standard module (project/add module).  Then remove the form module.  Then add a Sub called Main() in the standard module.  Your application will call Main() to start up.